# SQL syntax error while trying to create a new column with an if/else clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using this schema in PostgreSQL v9.6:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
  calendar_week_start timestamp,
  calendar_week_end timestamp,
  calendar_year integer,
  calendar_year_category varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO dates (calendar_week_start, calendar_week_end, calendar_year, calendar_year_category)
VALUES ((DATE'2018-01-01'), (DATE'2018-01-07'), 2018, 'Prior Year'), 
       ((DATE'2018-01-08'), (DATE'2018-01-14'), 2018, 'Prior Year'), 
       ((DATE'2018-01-15'), (DATE'2018-01-21'), 2018, 'Prior Year'),
       ((DATE'2018-01-22'), (DATE'2018-01-28'), 2018, 'Prior Year'),
       ((DATE'2019-01-01'), (DATE'2019-01-07'), 2019, 'Current Year'), 
       ((DATE'2019-01-08'), (DATE'2019-01-14'), 2019, 'Current Year'), 
       ((DATE'2019-01-15'), (DATE'2019-01-21'), 2019, 'Current Year'),
       ((DATE'2019-01-22'), (DATE'2019-01-28'), 2019, 'Current Year');
```

And I am attempting to run this query to create a column called "latest_week" that should check both the `calendar_week_end` and `calendar_year_category` fields to determine whether the date is the latest week in the table or not, and assign a value of 'Yes' or 'No'.

Whenever I try a "dummy" query comparing two rows that exist, the query runs as expected. Whenever I try to use MAX(calendar_week_end) to compare the date values to the maximum date value, the queries start throwing errors.

Below is one such query that returns an unexpected error (with no other information given).

```
SELECT calendar_week_end GROUP BY calendar_year_category,
    CASE
        WHEN calendar_week_end=MAX(calendar_week_end) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END
    AS latest_week
FROM dates;
```

If I run this "dummy" query simply comparing `calendar_week_start` and `calendar_week_end`, however, the same syntax works and I get the new column `latest_week` with all values as 'No' as expected.

```
SELECT calendar_week_start, calendar_year_end GROUP BY calendar_week_category,
    CASE
        WHEN calendar_week_start=calendar_week_end THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END
    AS latest_week
FROM dates;
```

What is the proper syntax if I want to use MAX(calendar_week_end) in my query?

Comment: Unrelated, but: putting parentheses around a single date value `(DATE'2018-01-22')` is completely useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function.  The following creates a boolean, rather than a string:

```
SELECT d.*,
       ( 1 = row_number() over (order by calendar_week_end desc) ) as is_latest_week
FROM dates d;
```